# CGAffineTransformMakeRotation on CGPoint unexpected values

Tags: objective-c, ios7, cgaffinetransform, cgpoint

I am rotating CGPoints using a CGAffineTransformRotation

Executing this code:

```
double degToRad(double degrees) {
  return ((degrees) * (M_PI / 180.0));
}

CGAffineTransform rotate = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(degToRad(-90.0));

NSLog(@"before n.nP %@",NSStringFromCGPoint(node.nodePoint));

node.nodePoint = CGPointApplyAffineTransform(node.nodePoint, rotate);

NSLog(@"after  n.nP %@",NSStringFromCGPoint(node.nodePoint));
```

Gives these results:

```
before n.nP {96, 196}
after n.nP  {196, -95.999999999999986}
```

This is understandable; -95.999... as opposed to -96 is due to some internal rounding/the limit on the degree of expression of `M_PI`.  The degree of difference in this instance is negligible.

But these results:

```
before n.nP {0, 768}
after n.nP  {768, 4.702643708725836e-14}
```

...are what puzzle me.  I expect `{768, 0}` or pretty dang close as a return value.  Why is the degree of difference in this case so large?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the difference isn't so large. In fact, it's very tiny! Before we jump into *why* there is this difference, let's explain what that difference means:

`after n.np {768, 4.702643708725836e-14}`

Notice the `e-14` at the end. That means `4.702643708725836 x 10^-14`, or .`00000000000004702643708725836`, which is very close to 0. To learn more about *E Notation*, [read this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation#E_notation)!

Now, why this happens is both the inaccuracy of M_PI and [floating point representation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point). Floating point numbers (*floats*) are how the C language (and many others) represent non-integral (*int*) numbers. It uses an approximation-based method as it's impossible to represent all numbers in a realistic number of bits. *Doubles* are just like *floats*, but use two times as many bits (hence *double*) to represent real numbers, and thus have more accuracy. But they are still approximations, and sometimes have small artifacts of inaccuracy, and thus [you shouldn't directly compare floats typically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17333/most-effective-way-for-float-and-double-comparison).

Comment: OH MY GOODNESS of course I know about E notation, I just goofed and ignored it!  Your answer is accepted, especially as it didn't draw too much attention to my hasty silliness... FWIW, I added a floorf() post-calculation because in some cases I needed 4.702643708725836e-14 to be precisely 0